# Data trending across table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services

I'm trying to work out a trend over a sql table which contains entries for files entering filesystem folders over a set time period. I have a table that contains the date periods and another containing all of the folders that I am interested in. When I join (right outer) the two I get a table like below:

```
Jan 2012, folder A 2 
Jan 2012, folder B 4
Feb 2012, folder A 2
Feb 2012, folder B 2
```

However if no information has been entered for a date interval I just get null values so
March 2012, null, null

Is there any way that I can add a zero into this table for each folder? This would give me:

```
Jan 2012, folder A 2 
Jan 2012, folder B 4
Feb 2012, folder A 2
Feb 2012, folder B 2
Mar 2012, folder A 0
Mar 2012, folder B 0
```

I then need to work out a trend over the months for each folder so that the difference between Jan and Feb for folder A is 0 and -200% between Feb and Mar. This would give me a final table of:

```
Jan 2012, folder A 2 0 (first month no data)
Jan 2012, folder B 4 0 (first month no data)
Feb 2012, folder A 2 200% (increase on Jan)
Feb 2012, folder B 2 -50% (decrease on Jan)
Mar 2012, folder A 0 -200% (decrease on Feb)
Mar 2012, folder B 0 -200% (decrease on Feb)
```

This will eventually end up in an ssrs report so it doesn't matter if the trending happens in the query or through the report builder.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

My table schemas look like:

Folder Table:

```
DECLARE @folders TABLE ( folderId int, folderPath varchar(500))
```

Files Table:

```
DECLARE @filessAdded TABLE 
( fileId int, 
  parentId int, 
  folderPath varchar(500), 
  eventDate DATETIME, 
  folderId int );
```

Date Table - populated dynamically based on date intervals in given period eg months:

```
DECLARE @dates TABLE ( DateOf VARCHAR(500) );
```

My final query looks like the following:

```
select isnull(Total,0),
       folder,
       dates.DateOf,
       trend 
from @filesAdded as files
right join @dates as dates on files.DateOf = dates.DateOf
```

Comment: What is the query you are currently using?  What does your data schema look like (i.e., table & field names)?

Comment: @Kievia: Shouldn't the %changes column read: 0, 0, 0, -50%, -100%, -100% ?

Comment: Yeah- case of writing too late

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest changing the query to be:

```
with cte as
(select d.DateOf,
        f.folderPath,
        count(case when datediff(month,f.DateOf,d.DateOf) = 0 then a.fileId end)
             fileCount,
        dense_rank() over (partition by f.folderPath order by d.DateOf) dr
 from @dates d
 cross join @folders f
 left join @filessAdded a on f.folderId = a.folderId
 group by d.DateOf, f.folderPath)
select c1.*, 
       case when coalesce(c0.fileCount, 0) = 0 then 0 
            else (c1.fileCount - c0.fileCount) / c0.fileCount 
       end perChange
from cte c1
left join cte c0 on c1.folderPath = c0.folderPath and c1.dr - 1 = c0.dr
```

Note that you will need to change the datediff condition when summing over periods other by months. (Alternatively, you could populate `@dates` with start and end date columns instead of a single date column, and then change the query condition to be based on whether the `@filessAdded` date was between the `@dates` start and end dates.)

Comment: We ended up going for the start and end date columns and recalculating how the dates where calculated-previously a date only got written once a file was added to the folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the second output with an outer join and use isnull(filedate,0).   I suspect you are using left when you should be using right but you don't give enough detail.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I use a left join I lose all of the rows where I don't have a file entering the folder and get: * Jan folder A 3 * Mar folder A 4 The right join keeps my date column but loses the folder: * Jan folder A 3 * Feb null null * Mar folder A 4 Ideally I would like Feb to read folder A 0 but I don't know how